# Подбор цифрового кода

Tags: алгоритм

Известно, что код состоит из 4 цифр. Так же известно, что все цифры разные.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, оптимальный алгоритм для перебора значений от 0000 до 9999. Искренне буду благодарен за псевдокод.

Comment: В конечном счёте для гарантированного нахождения ответа всё равно потребуется 10000 итераций. О какой оптимальности может идти речь?

Comment: @D-side побуду занудой. Не 10000, а меньше, т.к в условии указано "все цифры разные"

Comment: @KromStern ну лааааадно, 5040 (`[*0..9].permutation(4).count`). Даже не вдвое меньше :P

Comment: @D-side допустим эти цифры можно только вручную ввести (механический замок), тогда `10*9*8*7 == 5040` заметно меньше `10000` даже если робот код вводит за вас. Также (но другой вопрос) интересно алгоритм рассмотреть, который одинаково изнашивал бы [колёсики с цифрами (если хочется замок в сохранности оставить)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BAzRj.jpg)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В лоб – четырьмя вложенными циклами по каждой из цифр (будто крутим колёсики замка на чемодане). Для цифр правее первой проверяем, чтобы не совпадала с цифрами левее. Если нужно именно подобрать код в описанных условиях, нет смысла париться с оптимизацией.

```
var a, b, c, d, result=[];
for( a=0; a<10; a++) {
  for( b=0; b<10; b++) {
    if( b === a) continue;
    for( c=0; c<10; c++) {
      if( c===a  ||  c===b) continue;
      for( d=0; d<10; d++) {
        if( d===a || d===b || d===c) continue;
        // abcd из разных цифр
        result.push( ''+a+b+c+d);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Upd.** Наверное, можно оптимизировать. При переборе цифр слева направо, на первой позиции 10 вариантов, на второй 9, на третьей 8, и в правой только 7. Вместо 10000 итераций всего 5040. Но ничего лучше массива и сортировки пока не придумал. Фиговая оптимизация:

```
var a,b,c,d,A,B,C,D,U,result=[];
for( a=0; a<10; a++) {
  for( b=0; b<9; b++) {
    for( c=0; c<8; c++) {
      for( d=0; d<7; d++) {
        A = a;
        B = b; if( B>=A) B++;
        U = [A,B].sort();
        C = c; if( C>=U[0]) C++; if(C>=U[1]) C++;
        U = [A,B,C].sort();
        D = d; if( D>=U[0]) D++; if(D>=U[1]) D++; if( D>=U[2]) D++;

        result.push( ''+A+B+C+D);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

То, что вам нужно - это генерация *всех размещений без повторений*, или (в английском варианте) *k-permutations*.

Грубо говоря, - ищите все сочетания по 4 цифры из 10, и для каждого сочетания перебирайте все перестановки. Это если глобально.

Псевдокод - вот (простите, не получается нормально индексы показать, пришлось про-TeX'овски...):

```
def a = { 0, 1, 2 … (n - 1) }
def edge = k - 1

// find j in (k…n-1) where a_j > a_edge
j = k
while j < n and a_edge >= a_j,
    ++j

if j < n {
    swap a_edge, a_j
} else {
    reverse a_k to a_{n-1}

    // find rightmost ascent to left of edge
    i = edge - 1
    while i >= 0 and a_i >= a_i + 1,
          --i

    if i < 0,
          // no more permutations
          return 0

    // find j in (n-1…i+1) where a_j > a_i
    j = n - 1
    while j > i and a_i >= a_j
          --j

    swap a_i, a_j
    reverse a_{i+1} to a_{n-1}
}

output a_0, a_1 … a_{k-1}
```

Взято [отсюда](https://alistairisrael.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/simple-efficient-pnk-algorithm/).

Comment: На Питоне: [`k_permutations = (code for comb in combinations(range(10), 4) for code in permutations(comb))`](http://ideone.com/nJP3EX)